# Real analysis: are things really more complicated than they seem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm studying real analysis out of [Pugh's book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14544159803258717604). Consider this theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[a,b]$. Then $f$ has an absolute maximum and minimum.

This seems obvious, but it isn't as easy to prove as our intuition suggests (I have Pugh's proof in mind). This is typical in real analysis. Furthermore, the proof that Pugh gives doesn't explain why the theorem is intuitively obvious to us.

**Question:** Is there a "pathological" continuous function that illustrates why this theorem isn't as easy to prove as our intuition suggests? That is to say, is there an example that can make us doubt our intuition regarding this particular theorem?

Comment: What about this seems especially complicated to you?  You say that your intuition leads you to believe that it is true, and you have a proof.  What more do you want?

Comment: @Xander, the epsilontic arguments for this do seem convoluted.

Comment: In what way?  Can you *explain* your discomfort?  Where, precisely, does the argument seem complicated?

Comment: @Xander, there are two aspects of Hugh's proof that may cause "discomfort".  First, he needs a preliminary result (theorem 22) about the range being bounded.  Furthermore, the proof of the result in question (theorem 23) happens to be a proof by contradiction.  Such proofs are not always the most convincing.

Comment: I don't quite see the point of this question, one attempt one can try to analyze this is to write the proof of this and then, see which steps are potentially problematic. So far it just seems to attract lots of attention of people that just "say words".

Comment: If it seems obvious to you, try to come up with a pseudo proof based on yout intuition. Just put it on paper, without worries about being formal. Then you analyze where your intuitive proof "breaks".

Comment: @MikhailKatz Sure, but I am asking the *semisimpleton* to explain what *they* are finding confusing.  I can't read their mind.  I don't know where *their* discomfiture is coming from.  It is up to them to explain the problem.  Otherwise, this isn't an answerable question (and the sheer variety of answers here seems to indicate that no one really agrees on what the underlying problem is---for what it's worth, my suspicion is that this is a problem with the least upper bound property, which is the, in my experience, the thing that catches students up on this theorem).

Comment: Perhaps we can ask *semisimpleton* to comment on the three aspects of the proof that are potentially "isn't easy": (1) the use of the least upper bound property (which of course Pugh uses explicitly); (2) the fact that you need a separate preliminary result (theorem 22); (3) the fact that the proof of theorem 23 (the theorem under discussion) is a proof by contradiction.  Or perhaps all three?

Comment: @MikhailKatz That was the intention of my first comment (and my first reply which, in my hastiness, I assumed was in response to a comment by semisimpleton, and not some third party attempting to read their mind).

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with the proof, and it doesn't cause me any discomfort. I'm quite used to seeing (and producing) proofs like this. My question was, why isn't it as easy to prove this theorem as it is to intuit that it is true?

Comment: Maybe the reason that this feels obvious is that it often follows from a simpler principle: every finite set of numbers has a max and min.  Most functions we can easily imagine and have intuition for are built from finite number of operations or subdivisions (polynomials, piecewise monotone/linear/quadratic functions).  In many cases, a more direct, algorithmic argument for the existence of an absolute min or max can be given.  On the other hand, an infinite set of numbers need not have a maximum, and a general continuous function can satisfy an infinite number of pointwise constraints.

Comment: @semisimpleton Many things in in math are "intuitively obvious", but translating that intuition into a proof can be hard.  Sometimes, our intuition is simply wrong, other times our intuition doesn't account for the full generality of an idea, etc.

Comment: Can you explain why you find this theorem "intuitively obvious"?  It sounds like there is a serious gap in your intuition, but it's hard to address that gap without knowing exactly what your intuition is.  (You keep talking about "*our* intuition", but I suspect your intuition is far less universal than you believe it to be!)

Comment: In particular, to me the intuition behind this theorem comes entirely from the ideas behind its proof.  I don't have any intuition for it that would lead me to expect a simpler proof.

Comment: I suspect my intuition is "empirical"; the theorem is obviously true for every continuous curve on a closed interval that I can imagine. That's why I asked in my original post if there are examples that can make me doubt my intuition. And yes, I do think my intuition is quite universal! After all, mathematicians would never have tried to prove this theorem if they didn't already suspect it to be true. Mathematicians believed in the truth of this theorem *before* they came up with a rigorous proof.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have *far* too much faith in your imagination!  To me, a theorem being obviously true for every example I can imagine would make me *suspect* a theorem is true, but would certainly not make me call it "intuitively obvious".

Comment: You should probably look for a [nowhere differentiable function](https://planetmath.org/nowheredifferentiable). Our mental pictures of continuous functions are usually $C^1$ curves. In this case, the theorem in question is indeed intuitive: since $f'$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is a connected space, $f'([a,b])$ is also connected, i.e., the curve of $f'$ shouldn't be “broken”. Therefore $f$ is either monotonic or it has critical points. As local maxima must occur at critical points, the maximum of $f$ can be obtained by comparing the values of $f$ at the critical values with $f(a)$ and $f(b)$...

Comment: ... So, in this case, the proof involves only connectedness, which is a very intuitive concept. In contrast, for a general continuous function $f$, the proof of the theorem involves the notion of compactness (of $[a,b]$), which is far less intuitive.

Comment: @semisimple, you may want to incorporate your comment "I'm perfectly happy with the proof, and it doesn't cause me any discomfort. I'm quite used to seeing (and producing) proofs like this. My question was, why isn't it as easy to prove this theorem as it is to intuit that it is true?" in the body of the question so as to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @Xander, it is true that, as you wrote above, "Many things in in math are 'intuitively obvious', but translating that intuition into a proof can be hard".  However, in this case, the OP's hunch that the proof is unnecessarily hard is right on target, as illustrated in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4766619/72694).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help to note that a relaxation in any of the conditions of the theorem mean that it's no longer true.

- If the interval is not closed, the theorem doesn't hold. For example, \begin{align*} f \colon (0,1] &\to \mathbb R \\ x &\mapsto \tfrac 1x\end{align*}
  has no absolute maximum.
- If the interval is not finite, the theorem doesn't hold. For example, \begin{align*} f \colon [1, \infty) &\to \mathbb R \\ x &\mapsto \tfrac 1x \end{align*} has no absolute minimum.
- If the function is not continuous, the theorem doesn't hold. For example, \begin{align*} f \colon [0,1] &\to \mathbb R \\ x &\mapsto \begin{cases} x & x \in (0, 1], \\ 1 & x=0\end{cases}\end{align*}
  has no absolute minimum.

So perhaps it's not as obvious as it first seems: every part of the theorem is important and cannot be relaxed.

Comment: If we use $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ (with domain a closed interval in $\mathbb{Q}$), the theorem doesn't hold.

Comment: @aschepler I think that *this* is actually the key insight.  In my opinion, the extreme value theorem isn't *really* a theorem about continuity.  It is actually a theorem about the real numbers (the least upper bound property, in particular), and *that* is what makes it hard (because the real numbers are super crazy complicated and hard to understand, yet we are told from a very early age that they are real, therefore obvious).

Comment: @XanderHenderson: the same holds for intermediate value theorem as well. Timothy Gowers once explained this in his post https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/reals.html (part 3 deals with intermediate value theorem).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Indeed.  I think that most of the difficulty of real analysis comes not the "analysis" part of the course, but the "real" part.  The principal difficulty (in my opinion) is getting a handle of the real numbers.

Comment: OP: for an example of a function $f:[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ with no absolute minimum, set $f(x)=|1-2x^2|$.

Answer (score 3):

In the second half of the 19th century, mathematicians noticed that certain things about the convergence of Fourier series, as well as existence of minimizers in the calculus of variations, that seemed "obvious" were actually incorrect.  Similarly, examples were found of continuous functions that don't have the "intuitively" expected properties, such as existence of derivative at most points, which taught mathematicians to be more prudent about passing from intuitively obvious to mathematically proven.  In the case of continous functions on a compact interval, it could be argued that if the function satisfies a Lipschitz condition, the existence of maxima and minima should be obvious.  However, the general case requires a more precise argument.

The OP clarified his question in [this
comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766615/real-analysis-are-things-really-more-complicated-than-they-seem/4766619#comment10123119_4766615)
in the following terms: "I'm perfectly happy with the proof, and it
doesn't cause me any discomfort.  I'm quite used to seeing (and
producing) proofs like this.  My question was, why isn't it as easy to
prove this theorem as it is to intuit that it is true?"  This is a
good question.  Therefore I will provide an intuitive proof along the
lines suggested by user f3q in [this
comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766615/real-analysis-are-things-really-more-complicated-than-they-seem/4766619#comment10123121_4766615).

The proof works in axiomatic frameworks for nonstandard analysis as
outlined for example
[here](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/spot.html), on the interval
$I=[0,1]$ for simplicity.  Let $n$ be a nonstandard integer, and
consider a uniform partition of the interval $I$ into subintervals of
length $\frac1{n}$, with division points
$0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n=1$.  Among the finitely many division
points, choose the point $x_i$ where the function $f$ is maximal.  Let
$c$ be the standard part of $x_i$, i.e., the standard real number
infinitely close to $x_i$.  Since $I$ is closed, $c$ belongs to $I$.
Since $f$ is continuous, $f(c)$ is infinitely close to $f(x_i)$.  To
show that $c$ is a maximum, let $x\in I$ be any other standard point.
Then $x$ belongs to a suitable partition subinterval $[x_j,x_{j+1}]$
and in particular $x$ is infinitely close to $x_j$.  By definition of
$x_i$, we have $f(x_i)\geq f(x_j)$.  Applying standard part to both
sides (and using continuity of $f$), we obtain $f(c)\geq f(x)$, as
required.

The advantage of such a proof is that it requires no preliminary
results (such as Theorem 22 in Pugh), and it is not a proof by
contradiction (as Pugh's proof of Theorem 23) but rather a direct
proof.

However, I wouldn't use it on a test if you are asked to prove the
theorem.  You will either be misunderstood as claiming that one can
choose a maximum over an infinite set, or else told that you cannot
use material from outside the class to prove the course material.  I
provided the proof only as an illustration that it is indeed possible
to give a more intuitive proof than that given in Pugh.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my personal experience, the main reason that intuition sometimes looks uncertain and flawed (especially when facing a counter-intuitive fact), is that **what nourishes intuition is highly based on experience, and experience is limited.** This can explain the vital role of practicing over and over in math (it serves to improve your intuition, which, on the other hand, brings your problem-solving skill to next level). In my humble opinion, the main ground of your doubt is that perhaps you do not know sufficiently many functions that, although counter-intuitive (and therefore creative), violate the traditional viewpoints. You may be trying to digest this proof by imagining smooth-looking, nice-behaving functions such as $\sin x$ or $x^2$, but some functions like [the Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function#:%7E:text=of%20the%20set%20of%20rational,mathematician%20Peter%20Gustav%20Lejeune%20Dirichlet.) or [the Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) also exist and constitute a class of counter-intuitive, yet wonderful examples.

**Conclusion**

In mathematics, practice more and learn more examples, so as to have stronger intuition and more things obvious to you.

**P.S.**

I hope this post adds to shedding more light on the subject under question. The other posts provide more analytical examples that are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive proof. Since a continuous function maps compact sets onto compact sets and connected sets onto connected sets, $f([a,b])$ is also compact and connected. Moreover, any compact connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is a closed bounded interval, so $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ for some $-\infty<c\le d<+\infty$. By the way, the connectedness condition can be dropped in the extreme value theorem, whose proof is still relatively easy but less intuitive.

Comment: I would think that this would only be intuitive to someone who already knows a reasonable amount of basic point-set topology.  At most American institutions (the kind with which I am familiar), topology is typically taught *after* real analysis.

Comment: I'm a self-learner and indeed I tried to learn real analysis first. However, I find real analysis extremely abstract and counterintuitive and often in need of knowledge of topology and set theory, so I decided to learn these two first :X But a continuous function mapping a closed bounded interval onto a closed bounded interval is intuitive at least to me before I learned topology.

Comment: Note the difference between closed interval and closed bounded interval.

Comment: Hugh's proof does not assume that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.  Rather, in a preliminary theorem 22, he proves that the image of the function is bounded.  Then in theorem 23 he uses a proof by contradiction to establish the result.

Comment: I'd argue this is somewhat a good argument when it comes to intuition, but connectedness and compactness can actually be somewhat unintuitive. So at the same time, maybe it's the wrong kind of intuition? I think seeing an explicit argument is what would appeal to the OP more.